# How to use Replace() to replace HTML encoded characters in a string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have some HTML encoded content which I'm placing in a meta tag. I need to replace the line breaks in it which is represented in HTML encoded text as `&lt;br &#x2f;&gt;`.

I thought I could do this:

```
#Replace(rsResult.Description, '&lt;br &#x2f;&gt;', '', 'ALL')#
```

But it keeps throwing an error. The HTML encoded part that I want to remove is whats causing the issue. I don't know why CF can't treat that part as the text to remove from the string.

How could I do this successfully?

Comment: You've got your answer, but for future reference, when you get an error, don't forget to actually provide us with the error. It wasn't necessary this time, but in general it's good troubleshooting info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape # character.
So your code should be like
`#Replace(rsResult.Description, '&lt;br &##x2f;&gt;', '', 'ALL')#`